# How to create a paraview animation from python script?

Tags: python, animation, visualization, paraview

So, I have a set of vtk files named file_0.vtk, file_1.vtk ... In paraview I can read all these files, choose a variable ( for example 'V'), create slices in the Z direction then save a temporal animation. I get a nice movie.

Now, I wonder if it is possible to get the same result automatically in python without using the paraview interface, i.e. just by doing :

```
python3 ./animation.py
```

I know that it is possible to save python scripts in python from the commands we do through paraview or even use python from paraview, but I don't know how to create the animation without using the software.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `SaveAnimation()` method at the end of the python script for your pipeline. See [this doc](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/savingResults.html#saving-animation) (python part at the end of the section).

If you want to see the animation at runtime, then add the `AnimateReader(reader, view)` method instead. [Here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/blob/f463550cb254eb7cd8ea650489061ee1b68bbdcb/Wrapping/Python/paraview/servermanager.py#L3113) is an example.